# React Build not loading some images

Tags: reactjs, webpack

here's my github project
https://github.com/MangoYumm/Fashion

I have my main index.html public/index.html
app.js from src/app.js controls the frontend , which is made of Header,Body,Footer and all these have images in them.
"npm run start" works fine and everything is displayed when I run public/index.html.

now when I use "npm run build" , and run build/index.html , it doesn't show all the images. Only the F icon in Header is shown, and the stars in part1 of Body.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the repo and tried to run the project both with start and after building it.

Once you run: `npm run build` you then need to run the following:
`serve -s build` ( you may need to install it globally if it is not installed ).

React uses a variable called `PUBLIC_URL` to get the path to your resources it is the root path of your app. Opening just the index.html will not work as expected.

P.S.: no need to write `npm run start` you can also do this: `npm start`.
Hope it works!

Comment: Hi, serve -s build works fine for me too. But this project is part of another project and I need the build/index.html cuz I need to reference it in <a href="./../Fashion/build/index.html"> of another file. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: 1. Can you use one repo with multiple projects in it - monorepo?


2. You can try to use a script and copy your build folder into the public folder of the main project.


3. You can use micro-frontend architecture but for this you need very specific settings